# For each element of given vector, generate sequence with X, X-1, ..., X-(N-1)

Tags: r, vector, seq

So I have been trouble with creating a counter, hopefully you all will be able to help. Lets say I have a vector

```
x <- c(40,10,60)
```

The desired output would be a new matrix 3 x n each row being a new date looking something like this..

```
40 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30...
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 
60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50
```

What I want is for the row to subtract one from the previous entry an n number 
of times. How would I go about doing this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: *"The desired output would be a new vector 3 x n"*. There's no such thing as a "3 x n vector". Do you mean a matrix, an array or a dataframe?

Comment: Also, from `4 3 2 1 0 0 0 `, you want the number/data sequence clamped at 0 (can't go negative). One way is to use `pmax`.

Comment: `t(mapply(function(y) c(rev(sequence(y)), rep(0, max(x) + 1 - y)), x))`

Comment: Yes I am sorry, I do mean matrix.

Comment: @smci Thanks.  I was confused earlier with the `...`

Comment: @akrun I was confused too so I just assumed it implied an unnamed parameter `n` and carried on ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> n = 12 # or whatever you want

> t(sapply(c(40,10,60), function(x) pmax(seq(x, (x-n+1), -1), 0) ))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
[1,]   40   39   38   37   36   35   34   33   32    31    30    29    28
[2,]   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2     1     0     0     0
[3,]   60   59   58   57   56   55   54   53   52    51    50    49    48
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Very concise, thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: Welcome! Learn to love the `*apply` family.

Comment: Yeah I knew the answer was going to be in the *apply function, but the seq stuff would have gone right over me.

Comment: Sure. Have a look at the documentation for `seq` and its variants `seq_along, seq_len`. Together they can generate any (arithmetic) sequence you might want. Then by scaling and multiplying, you can get any numeric sequence.

Comment: I think you can also do `matrix(pmax(x- rep(sequence(n+1)-1,each=length(x)),0),nrow=3)`

Comment: @akrun can you fix that syntax, and post as an answer? If so, you win the golf.

Comment: Here `x <- c(40, 10, 60)`.  and `nrow=length(x))`.  I am getting the same result as yours.  But, it is basically your solution.  So, I better leave it here :-)